# Custom Encoder, unable to record video

Tags: python, camera

I used the below mentioned customer encoder to simultaneously record video as print a file containing time stamp values of each frame.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

import io
import picamera
import socket
import time
import datetime as dt

WIDTH  = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FRAMERATE = 30
EXPOSURE_MODE = 'night'
BRIGHTNESS = 60
CONTRAST = 20
SHARPNESS = 25
AWB_MODE = 'off'
AWB_GAINS = 1.7

# An output (as far as picamera is concerned), is just a filename or an object
# which implements a write() method (and optionally the flush() and close()
# methods)
class MyOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, camera, video_filename, pts_filename):
        self.camera = camera
        self.videoOutputFile = io.open(video_filename, 'wb')
        self.timestampOutputFile = io.open(pts_filename, 'w')
        self.start_time = None

    def write(self, buf):
        self.videoOutputFile.write(buf)
        if self.camera.frame.complete and self.camera.frame.timestamp:
            if self.start_time == None:
                self.start = self.camera.frame.timestamp
        self.timestampOutputFile.write(u'%f, %s\n' % (((self.camera.frame.timestamp-self.start_time)/1000.0), dt.datetime.now().strfime("%H:%M:%S.%f")))

    def flush(self):
        self.videoOutputFile.flush()
        self.timestampOutputFile.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.videoOutputFile.close()
        self.timestampOutputFile.close()


runningTimeHours = raw_input('Enter the number of hours you want to record:')
runningTimeHours = float(runningTimeHours)

runningTimeMinutes = raw_input('Enter the number of minutes you want to record:')
runningTimeMinutes = float(runningTimeMinutes)

runningTimeSeconds = raw_input('Enter the number of seconds you want to record:')
runningTimeSeconds = float(runningTimeSeconds)

totalRunningTime = runningTimeHours*60*60 + runningTimeMinutes*60 + runningTimeSeconds


videoFileName = "output" + str(dt.datetime.now()) + ".h264"
timestampFileName = "timestamp" + str(dt.datetime.now()) + ".txt"

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    camera.framerate = FRAMERATE
    camera.brightness = BRIGHTNESS
    camera.contrast = CONTRAST
    camera.sharpness = SHARPNESS

    #warm-up time to camera to set its initial settings
    time.sleep(2)

    camera.exposure_mode = EXPOSURE_MODE
    camera.awb_mode = AWB_MODE
    camera.awb_gains = AWB_GAINS

    #time to let camera change parameters according to exposure and AWB
    time.sleep(2)

    camera.exposure_mode = 'off'    

    # Construct an instance of our custom output splitter with a filename  and a connected socket
    print 'Starting Recording'
    # Record video to the custom output (we need to specify the format as
    # the custom output doesn't pretend to be a file with a filename)
    camera.start_recording(MyOutput(camera, videoFileName, timestampFileName), format='h264')
    print 'Started Recording'
    camera.wait_recording(totalRunningTime)
    camera.stop_recording()
    print 'Recording Stopped'
    print 'Output File Closed'
```

and I am getting following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_final.py", line 90, in <module>
    print 'Output File Closed'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 976, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 955, in close
    self.stop_recording(splitter_port=port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1362, in stop_recording
    self.wait_recording(0, splitter_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1333, in wait_recording
    encoder.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 853, in wait
    raise self.exception
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'long' and 'NoneType'
```

Kindly help me correct the issue please.

Comment: This question best fits Stack Overflow.

Comment: The exception is complaining that long and None can't be subtracted; the only place you're using subtraction is in your calculation of the time elapsed so I would suggest having a look around there. I can see one mistake in that you're setting self.start instead of self.start_time but even then there's no guarantee you'll get a valid timestamp on the first few frames (the first frame is usually a config frame which has timestamp None for example)

Comment: Oh, and there's another error: you want strftime instead of strfime for formatting the system's timestamp

Comment: Hey thanks Dave. I resolved the issue, kind of silly mistake from my side.

Comment: Do you want to write your own answer to this then or should I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 main errors in the code, 1.) self.start_time == None which is the wrong way to compare. As a result of this, the start_time variable is not initialized and hence the error in subtraction. 2.) also for printing strftime was required rather than strfime. Here is the updated script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

import io
import picamera
import socket
import time
import datetime as dt
import sys, getopt
from fractions import Fraction

WIDTH  = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FRAMERATE = 30
VIDEO_STABILIZATION = True
EXPOSURE_MODE = 'night'
BRIGHTNESS = 60
CONTRAST = 30
SHARPNESS = 30
AWB_MODE = 'off'
AWB_GAINS = 1.4

VIDEO_FILE_NAME = "cam1_output_" + str(dt.datetime.now()) + ".h264"
TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME = "cam1_timestamp_" + str(dt.datetime.now()) + ".txt"
runningTimeHours, runningTimeMinutes, runningTimeSeconds = 0,0,0

# An output (as far as picamera is concerned), is just a filename or an object
# which implements a write() method (and optionally the flush() and close()
# methods)
class MyOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, camera, video_filename, pts_filename):
        self.camera = camera
        self.videoOutputFile = io.open(video_filename, 'wb')
        self.timestampOutputFile = io.open(pts_filename, 'w')
        self.start_time = None

    def write(self, buf):
        self.videoOutputFile.write(buf)
        if self.camera.frame.complete and self.camera.frame.timestamp:
            if self.start_time is None:
                self.start_time = self.camera.frame.timestamp
            self.timestampOutputFile.write(u'%f, %s\n' % (((self.camera.frame.timestamp-self.start_time)/1000.0), dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")))
        #print self.camera.awb_gains, self.camera.digital_gain, self.camera.analog_gain, self.camera.brightness, self.camera.contrast, self.camera.saturation , camera.exposure_speed 

    def flush(self):
        self.videoOutputFile.flush()
        self.timestampOutputFile.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.videoOutputFile.close()
        self.timestampOutputFile.close()

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'r:m:s:h', ['help',"hour=", "min=", "sec="])
except getopt.GetoptError, err: 
    print err
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'): 
        print "Acquire_code.py -hr <hours> -m <mins> -s <secs>"
    elif opt in ('-r','--hour'):
        runningTimeHours = arg
    elif opt in ('-m','--min'):
        runningTimeMinutes = arg
    elif opt in ('-s','--sec'):
        runningTimeSeconds = arg

runningTimeHours = float(runningTimeHours)
runningTimeMinutes = float(runningTimeMinutes)
runningTimeSeconds = float(runningTimeSeconds)

totalRunningTime = runningTimeHours*60*60 + runningTimeMinutes*60 + runningTimeSeconds

#print totalRunningTime

try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        camera.framerate = FRAMERATE
        camera.brightness = BRIGHTNESS
        camera.contrast = CONTRAST
        camera.sharpness = SHARPNESS
        camera.video_stabilization = VIDEO_STABILIZATION

        #warm-up time to camera to set its initial settings
        time.sleep(2)

        camera.exposure_mode = EXPOSURE_MODE
        camera.awb_mode = AWB_MODE
        camera.awb_gains = AWB_GAINS

        #time to let camera change parameters according to exposure and AWB
        time.sleep(2)

        camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
        camera.hflip = False
        camera.vflip = False

        camera.start_preview()
        # Construct an instance of our custom output splitter with a filename  and a connected socket
        print 'Starting Recording'
        # Record video to the custom output (we need to specify the format as
        # the custom output doesn't pretend to be a file with a filename)
        camera.start_recording(MyOutput(camera, VIDEO_FILE_NAME, TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME), format='h264')
        print 'Started Recording'
        camera.wait_recording(totalRunningTime)
        camera.stop_recording()
        camera.stop_preview()
        print 'Recording Stopped'
        print 'Output File Closed'
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Closing Output File'
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: Whilst this code may work, it would be wise to include some explanation.